# Is there an IMAP server that supports searching emails using elasticsearch or solr?

Tags: email, imap, solr

What I am wondering is if there is an IMAP server available that supports the IMAP `SEARCH` command (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1730#section-6.4.4), and is fast.

I have had a look around at ways that this can be done, including using DBMail to store all of the incoming emails, but to be honest so far what I have found is that most of the IMAP solutions have some sort of downfall - none really seem to be aimed specifically at what I want to do.

For example, DBMail is almost perfect, however it stores attachments in the database. What I would love to have is that inside the database all of the messages (HTML, TXT) are stored, but the attachments are stored somewhere else on the filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dovecot should : http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/FTS/Solr I never test solr on it.

Comment: ha! I was just going to answer my own question with that exact link :) Turns out that my Googlefu started working after an hour.

Comment: As Dom says, Dovecot does Solr, but I don't think you are going to find SQL mailstores. About the only example I've seen of something similar was amavisd, you could use an SQL mailstore for viruses and spam.

Comment: ? I've only heard of using amavisd as a AV scanner milter. Akonadi can use MySQL or SQLite backends - although I'm not a fan.

Answer (score 1):

I've just pushed a very experimental plugin for FTS using ElasticSearch in Dovecot as well.

https://github.com/ascendantcom/fts-elasticsearch

Although this question is old it's still the top hit for ElasticSearch in Dovecot.

Comment: Nice work! I am going to look over this later tonight and let you know if I find any issues.